# Spring JDBC - Last inserted id

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I'm using Spring JDBC. Is a simple way to get last inserted ID using Spring Framework or i need to use some JDBC tricks ?

```
jdbcTemplate.update("insert into test (name) values(?)", params, types);
// last inserted id ...
```

I found something like below, but i get: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Returning autogenerated keys is not supported.`

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
jdbcTemplate.update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

    @Override
    public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(
            Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("insert into test (name) values(?)", new String[] {"id"});
        ps.setString(1, "test");
        return ps;
    }

}, keyHolder);
lastId = (Long) keyHolder.getKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old/standard way is to use call *[currval()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-sequence.html)* after the insert ([ref](http://neilconway.org/docs/sequences/)). Simple and secure.

Comment: Thanks. I did it this way: `jdbcTemplate.queryForLong("select currval('main_seq')");`

Answer (score 1):

Support for "generated keys for PreparedStatements" started only since PostgreSql Ver [8.4-701](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/changes.html#version_8.4-701).