# Returning the autoincremented value of the id after insert into a table

Tags: spring, auto-increment

I am using keyholder to get the id that is automatically incremented while inserting. It works fine on the actual table.

I have a synonym table in another database which actually points to the original table and I have to do the insert into the synonym table. The method used is returning 0 for keyholder.getkey() when I try to do the insert in the synonym table. Please help me..

References:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241003/how-to-get-a-value-from-the-last-inserted-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597477/getting-auto-generated-key-from-row-insertion-in-spring-3-postgresql-8-4-9)
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html#jdbc-auto-genereted-keys

ADD:

I have tried

```
 String sql = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) values(?, ?)";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
stmt.executeUpdate();
if(returnLastInsertId) {
   ResultSet rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
    rs.next();
   auto_id = rs.getInt(1);
}
```

But this is returning 0 too. Why is this not working in a synonym table? I mean it inserts the auto incremented value but return '0'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue, I have used a function called getSerial() to get the serial. 
Thanks for checking out!