# Need to get the auto generated id when a stored proc run

Tags: spring-mvc

I am inserting the data using stored proc and i need the  id after insertion with the stored proc

Lets say

Mystoreproc: insert into x values y
Once i run this stored proc i need to get the value of auto-generated id.  Because i am using this id as a foreign key to to the another tables.

I tried the same solution ofhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597477/getting-auto-generated-key-from-row-insertion-in-spring-3-postgresql-8-4-9

This is working fine without stored proc call.  The same thing i tried with call myatoreproc(¿)
It is inserting the data but unable to return the auto generated id.

Apache is throwing an error automatically keys were not generated.

Not sure how to implement this.