# How to get insertion id from database? Spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

i am trying to get insertion id from postgres database. My code now looks like:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (name) VALUES (?);";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, account.name);
```

id is generated automatically.

How should I change this code, that it would return the row id of the inserted account?

Comment: It seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061409/7940179) answer might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleJdbcInsert to insert values and get generated keys from operation.

```
public class JdbcActorDao implements ActorDao {

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
private SimpleJdbcInsert insertActor;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    this.insertActor = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource)
            .withTableName("t_actor")
            .usingGeneratedKeyColumns("id");
}

public void add(Actor actor) {
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
    parameters.put("first_name", actor.getFirstName());
    parameters.put("last_name", actor.getLastName());
    Number newId = insertActor.executeAndReturnKey(parameters);
    actor.setId(newId.longValue());
 }  
}
```