# JdbcTemplate return UUID on insert "A result was returned when none was expected."

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

My insert query returns the UUID of the record that was inserted. Below is the relevant code.

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();

template.update(connection -> {
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
    ps.setString(1, stateName);
    ps.setString(2, stateAb);
    ps.setObject(3, propertyDetailsObject);


    return ps;
}, keyHolder);
```

I'm using a long CTE query that ends with `select id from tmpproperty limit 1;` I have shortened things here for easier readability.

But I get the following exception

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   PreparedStatementCallback; A result was returned when none was
>   expected.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A
>   result was returned when none was expected.

I found the above example online and was expecting it to work. Any idea what I should be doing differently?

Comment: What's the query in the insertQuery? Why do you have 'select id...' in the update query? This is your error: update query should not return any value, you are doing select at the end to return last row id. This is not a valid scenario for the update query.

Comment: You should use INSERT...RETURNING, ex: INSERT INTO persons (lastname,firstname) VALUES ('Smith', 'John') RETURNING id;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597477/getting-auto-generated-key-from-row-insertion-in-spring-3-postgresql-8-4-9

Answer (score 0):

Need to change to:

```
PreparedStatement ps =  connection.prepareStatement(youSQL, new String[]{"id"});
```

where `id` is the primary key column name

And remove `select id from tmpproperty limit 1;`, update query will be enough.

Comment: I'm using a CTE query, I think I need to have some kind of select after the CTE queries? Here is the full query https://pastebin.com/eGDHDfUh I always want to get the property.id, if it was just inserted, or if it already exists. The query works as expected right now. Not sure how to modify it so there would be no select.

Comment: I think your query should be executed with 'execute' or 'query' method, not 'update'. JDBCTemplate update method is designed for simple single inserts, not such complex insert that you have.